# Design pattern for adding / removing elements

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator

Wikipedia's definition for Iterator pattern design: *the Iterator pattern is a design pattern in which iterators are used to access the elements of an aggregate object sequentially without exposing its underlying implementation.*

Iterator interface in java provides the following methods

- hasNext()
- next()
- remove()

Is there a pattern design, or a java interface for inserting / deleting elements, and getting length of the aggregate object, in addition to iterating them? I know remove() is an optional method that can be used once per call to next(), but I am implementing a circular FIFO array and need a method delete() independent of iterator's next().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections are what you add to and remove from. Have a look at the [Collection interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). The Collection interface also has an iterator() method allowing you to iterate the collection.

Answer (score 2):

[ListIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) extends [Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) also has some cool methods

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Collection?
Btw, I'm wondering - if Iterator is considered a design pattern.. we can consider List and Map, and Queue (and not only) as design patterns as well? Since they already address the 'commonly occurring problem', and we can find them in most of other languages/libraries. So that's sort of "Family of Collections design sub-patterns" =)